# How can I display text AND variables in a tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter, widget

I asked a question yesterday explaining a basic calculator I was making. So far, I haven't been able to get text to display AT ALL in a text widget. This is what I'm using:

```
text = Tk()

ans_text = Text(text, width=40, height=10)
ans_text.pack

ans_text.insert("1.0", 0, 'test')

mainloop()
```

That's just something from effbot with modified variables. I haven't bothered to create any classes or define functions, except for the mathematical functions used in this "calculator." I don't exactly see the need to.

So how can I get text to display? I've just seen stuff about making a canvas and I don't really understand that. I just went some letters and numbers to show up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text (a zero) is being inserted, but the widget isn't visible which is why you aren't seeing it. You are forgetting the `()` when trying to pack the widget. Change the pack statement to look like this:

```
ans_text.pack()
```

With that modification your code will insert a zero as the first character of the text widget and apply the tag `text` to that character.

Whenever something doesn't appear the way  you expect, a really good first thing to try is to temporarily give the widget a distinctive color. It will then become obvious whether the widget isn't working the way you want (eg: text isn't being inserted), or it's working the way you want but it's not visible on the screen.

Comment: I forgot that. Thanks for correcting me! Aside from that, and back to the main "question" in my question, how can I get variables, specifically integers and floating points to display. Since it's a calculator I can't just type them in I need the variables to display.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you aware you can use variables when you call `ans_text.insert`?

Comment: Yeah, right after I commented I figured that out. Thanks for your  help!